# Get Param tag value in a page using Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page which is loading another page in it as follows :

```
<object type="text/html" data="test.html" width="800px" height="600px">
    <param name="data" value="hello">
</object>
```

Now I want to get the value of the 'param' tag on 'test.html' page how can I get it?
Right now I am trying to find a value of 'param' tag as follows but unfortunately I am unable to get the value.

```
var jsonData = document.getElementsByName('data');
console.log(jsonData)
```

Please can someone guide me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try console.log (jsonData )

Comment: With jQuery `alert($('object').find('param').val());`

Comment: Sorry I put the wrong variable. I have corrected it

Comment: try: document.getElementsByName('data')[0].value

Comment: Document.getElementsByName() returns a nodelist collection with a given name in the (X)HTML document.

Comment: I have tried all the options above but nothing working

Comment: @BASEERHAIDERJAFRI Hey did you ever get answer to this?